# How do I best map an unorganized point cloud back to it's organized ancestor?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I get an organized point cloud (using pcl and an ASUS Xtion Pro Live), which of course contains NANs and the like. I also get an RGB image of the same scene.

The first step for processing is removing those NANs, which converts the point cloud to unorganized. I then perform a few other steps, but that's not relevant to the question (I think, see P.S.1). What COULD (I'm not sure) be relevant is that I run extract multiple times, and so have quite a few intermediate point clouds. I believe this means I can no longer assume that the points are in the same order they were at the start.

For clarification, I do understand what an unorganized point cloud it and how it differs from unorganized, both theoretically and in terms of how the data is actually stored.

After chopping off various points, I now have a much smaller point cloud which consists only of points in the original point cloud (but much less of them). How do I map these points back to the matching points in the original point cloud? I probably could iterate through the entire cloud to find matches, but this seems hacked together. Is there a better way to do this?

My main aim is to be able to say that 'point A in my final point cloud is of interest to me' and furthermore to map that to pixel K in the RGB image I first obtained. It seems to me that matching the final point cloud with the initial one is the best way to do this, but alternatives are also welcome.

P.S.1 - One of the last few steps in my process is finding a convex hull and then extracting a polygonal prism from the original point cloud. If all else fails, I will just interrogate the (20-50) points on the convex hull to match them with my initial point cloud (minimizing computation) and hence to match them with the original RGB images.

P.S.2 - Random musing - since I know the original size of the RGB image, the origin of the camera relative to the point cloud (or, rather, the position of the points relative to the camera used to take them), and can trivially obtain the camera parameters, could I simply use ray-tracing through each point in my final point cloud to produce an RGB image? The image may need registration with the 'real' RGB image, or it probably won't since nothing will have actually moved except for rounding error.

Comment: All algorithms in PCL accept indices array in addition to the input point cloud. By supplying this indices array you restrict processing to a subset of points. Further, _some_ algorithms can output their results as indices into the input cloud rather than form a new output cloud (e.g. [this](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__filters.html#gaab4fb955a5a842af97545db7beee1da1) overload of `removeNaNFromPointCloud()`). Therefore, if you are lucky, you could construct a pipeline that works with the same point cloud, gradually changing an indices array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've looked at the processes I'm using and some don't really allow for indices-only processing. In particular, at one point I use ExtractIndices with setNegative = true, as I am at that point removing a plane found using RANSAC segmentation. It doesn't seem that there's a way to do that using indices, except perhaps manipulating the stl::vector<int> data inside my PointIndices. Tried a bit of that, got a few segfaults, and figured it was unlikely to be worth the effort, especially since I have no idea whether future functions I'm using will require pointclouds.

Comment: I can suggest another solution, though it's quite hacky. Choose a point type with additional field (say "label", or "intensity"), copy the original cloud inside and write original point indices into this field. Assuming that the algorithms that you use do not touch this field, you'll get your desired mapping in the end.

Comment: That actually seems fairly useful, especially if/when this gets larger scale. At this point, I'd need to benchmark to see how this performs against my initial plan (P.S.1). Basically a matter of an additional full copy vs doing some search. At the moment due to the simple geometry of my hull (eventually hope to get it down to a four-point rectangle with some smart vector maths), I think the latter will be preferable, but I can see how the first would work. I'm pretty sure most algorithms won't touch additional fields since I already use XYZRGBA and nothing goes missing except with ConcaveHull.